# How can I align equations to the left in latex

Tags: equations, align, right-to-left

How can I align equations to the left in latex?
[image]
this is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{nccmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{equation}\label{eq51}
\begin{aligned}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
|e||g_s|-\frac{e^2}{\epsilon+|e|}\bar{g}_s\leq0\\
|\hat{e}||\beta_s|-\frac{e^2|\hat{e}|}{e^2+\epsilon}\bar{\beta}_s\leq0\\
|e||u_c|/\bar{u}-\frac{e^2}{\epsilon+|e|}\bar{u}_c/\bar{u}\leq0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Within `aligned` simply place a `&` at the start of each line.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that equations should be sometimes centered and sometimes flush left. Choose your style and stick with it, which means “either use the `fleqn` document class option or not”.

If you want flush left equations (with some margin such as `\parindent`), you do

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for mock text

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\mathindent}{\parindent}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& |e||g_s|-\frac{e^2}{\epsilon+|e|}\bar{g}_s\leq0\\
& |\hat{e}||\beta_s|-\frac{e^2|\hat{e}|}{e^2+\epsilon}\bar{\beta}_s\leq0\\
& |e||u_c|/\bar{u}-\frac{e^2}{\epsilon+|e|}\bar{u}_c/\bar{u}\leq0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The initial `&` is needed because `aligned` makes pairs of columns, one *right* and one *left* aligned.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, try putting `&` at the beginning of every line, as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{nccmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{equation}\label{eq51}
\begin{aligned}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
& |e||g_s|-\frac{e^2}{\epsilon+|e|}\bar{g}_s\leq0\\
& |\hat{e}||\beta_s|-\frac{e^2|\hat{e}|}{e^2+\epsilon}\bar{\beta}_s\leq0\\
& |e||u_c|/\bar{u}-\frac{e^2}{\epsilon+|e|}\bar{u}_c/\bar{u}\leq0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]